# Should I say "I'm coming home 'at' / 'in' the next hour"?

Tags: prepositions

What is more native?

> I'm coming to the home **at** the next hour

or

> I'm coming to the home **in** the next hour

Comment: More common for the latter one is - *I'm coming in **an** hour*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning is different.

> "**At** the next hour"

means when the clock shows the next exact hour, no minutes, like 6:00 or 15:00.

> "**In** the next hour"

means within the next 60 minutes counting from *now*.

In other words, if "now" it's 16:45 (or a quarter to five in the afternoon), the "at" expression promises being at home at five in the afternoon, whereas the "in" expression promises being home at any time but no later than 5:45pm (17:45).

---

Also, remove the "to the" from "coming to the home":

> I'm **coming home** ...

Comment: It is, of course, possible to say *coming to the home* if you have a particular home, other than your own, in mind, and have some reason for not using a more specific word like house or apartment. I said something like that recently when I was arranging to meet a prospective tenant at a duplex/townhouse/apartment that I was renting out.

Comment: Yes, and also possible that by "home" he meant the facility where elderly and disabled people are housed.  Unlikely, though.

Comment: Also, while your explanation of “*at the next hour*” is indeed how this would be interpreted, nobody ***ever*** says “at the next hour”. If they mean they’ll be home at 6:00 they’ll say “I’ll be home at 6:00” [or by 6:00]” or “in 45 minutes’